# How we can insert absolute path using fileupload control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I am using *file upload* control using ASP.NET and I want to insert a absolute path into a database from *localhost* - like:-http://www.webcheck.co.in/rancMeUpload/hello.jpg.

When i am trying to do this it shows a exception:

> 'http:/www.webcheck.co.in/rancMeUpload/Jellyfish.jpg' is not a valid virtual path.

Here is my code:

```
protected void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (imageFileUpload.HasFile)
    {
        string str=imageFileUpload.FileName;
        imageFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"http://www.webcheck.co.in/rancMeUpload/"+str));
        string name="http://www.webcheck.co.in/rancMeUpload/"+str;

        int num = UseDetails.inserttechtpdate("inserttechupdates", titleTextBox.Text, descTextBox.Content , name, referenceTextBox.Text, postedByTextBox.Text);
        if (num > 0)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),"Message", "alert('Done');", true);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.. please follow as per Error.

Normally you can't upload file using url. you should have access to server folder where you want to upload the file.

If the folder is in same server where your code exists.

```
imageFileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~/rancMeUpload/"+str));
string name="http://www.webcheck.co.in/rancMeUpload/"+str;
```

simply change as above.

If not, then you have to do some more exercise.. like FTP access or any webService call to upload image on remote server. please confirm with first approach.